# How can I get the point pixel values to an array from Tiff using C#?

Tags: c#, tiff, libtiff, libtiff.net

I want to read the pixel values from Tiff images.

I have seen a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685070/32-bit-grayscale-tiff-with-floating-point-pixel-values-to-array-using-libtiff-ne), but I still have no idea how to deal with normal Tiff images.

Answer (score 1):

In [the samples](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples) of the [libtiff.net github repository](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net), there is one called [ReadSamples](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/ReadSamples) and the documentation states:

> This sample shows how to read RGB value of any pixel in a TIFF image.
>
> The library provides methods that can decode almost any TIFF image and
>   return array of packed RGBA values for its samples (pixels). This
>   sample shows how to use Tiff.ReadRGBAImage method to get packed sample
>   values and Tiff.GetA/GetB/GetG/GetR to unpack individual components of
>   an RGBA value.

[The code](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/blob/master/Samples/ReadSamples/C%23/ReadSamples.cs) is based on `ReadRGBAImage`, `Tiff.GetR`, `Tiff.GetG` and `Tiff.GetB` methods from the *libtiff.net* library.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have already get the array of an 8-bit TIFF image by this way. But using the same way, i get wrong array of an 16-bit TIFF image. I find a way from the link you give to convert the 16-bit image to an 8-bit one. But i'm not sure if i should convert it first when handling an 16-bit one. Is there a way to get the array directly from a 16-bit TIFF image or others rather than converting it first?

Comment: Based on the code here : https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/blob/master/Samples/Convert16BitTo8Bit/C%23/Convert16BitTo8Bit.cs#L72, `ReadScanline` fill the byte buffer with raw data, so, for a 16bit image, you have 16 bits data here, the `convertBuffer` (Convert16BitTo8Bit.cs#L87) method show that you can read byte two by two: `int value16 = buffer[src++]; value16 = value16 + (buffer[src++] << 8);`, it's big endian (the second byte store high weight data).