# Read pixel values from GeoTIFF in C#

Tags: c#, geospatial, tiff, geo, geotiff

I am trying to read the pixel values from a GeoTiff in C#.
The pixels represent elevation data.
The GeoTiff is:

- greyscaled
- contains float32 values
- non-tiled.

In Python this does exactly what i want:

```
tiffArray = numpy.array(tiffImage)
elevation = tiffArray[0,0] # returns: 39.66m
```

I tried **a lot** of solutions, mainly using the libTif library, which looks promising. But most expect tiled GeoTIFFs or fail in ways i do not understand (I dont know much about this low-level byte/binary/decoding stuff...). The GDAL library is apparently difficult to integrate into unity, so it is not a good alternative.

The sample GeoTIFF (just 2x2) can be downloaded here:
https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/ows/dgm_wcs?VERSION=2.0.1&SERVICE=wcs&REQUEST=GetCoverage&COVERAGEID=bb_dgm&FORMAT=image/tiff&SUBSET=x(389381,389384)&SUBSET=y(5820682,5820685)&SCALEFACTOR=1

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you show what you tried? The above code just indexes the image, without doing any GeoTIFF transformation. That is the easy part, by the way.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying! Indexing the GeoTIFF and reading the value. Can you show me how to do that?
I didnt include my tries, because too long/not leading anyhwere. This is one of the most promising approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685070/32-bit-grayscale-tiff-with-floating-point-pixel-values-to-array-using-libtiff-ne

Comment: Yea, that approach looks good. What did you get from that? (Note the comments in the code, you need to adjust it accordingly). What is the value of TIFFTAG_SAMPLEFORMAT for your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a library that exactly does the job.

Not easy to find, so here is a link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeoTiffElevationReader

Use it like this:

```
using GeoTiffElevationReader;

string filePath = "..../YourHeightMap.tif";
GeoTiff elevationTiff = new GeoTiff(filePath);
float elevation = elevationTiff.GetElevationAtLatLon((int)latitude, (int)longitude);
```

Gives out the elevation in meters (in this case).

It even takes the coordinates of the CRS of the GeoTIFF directly.